# How do I make test results public in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am playing around with an Azure Pipelines setup, where I run pytest and publish the results using https://pypi.org/project/pytest-azurepipelines/. This works fine, and [results show up on Azure in the "tests" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGV5f.png)

However, the tests tab is only visible when I am logged in. If I open the build job without being logged in only the "Summary" and "Code Coverage" tabs are visible, the "Tests" tab is not.

Can I make the tests tab publicly visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a design issue. You can click [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to report this issue to Microsoft development team.

Click  **Report a problem** and select **Azure Devops**. See below:

[image]

Comment: reported at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1054541/how-can-i-make-test-results-public-in-azure-pipeli.html